# What are the three fundamental elements of the CPU?

Tags: cpu

This question came in a previous computer exam. According to me, the answer is CU, ALU and something else.

I'm confused about whether that 'something else' is the registry or cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registers (not registry), or more abstractly onboard memory of some kind. The cache certainly isn’t fundamental; you can have a CPU with no cache at all and it will still work, just not as fast.